# How to completely remove the sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am custermising `adamos` theme with the WordPress web tool.

I went to `Appearance` ==> `Widgets`, and removed everything in `Primary Sidebar`.

But I still see `ARCHIVES` and `META` at the position of right sidebar on several pages.

Does anyone know how to remove the sidebar completely?

PS: here is the `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package adamos
 * @since adamos 1.0
 */
?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

            <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </aside>

            <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'adamos' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'adamos' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_register(); ?>
                    <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                    <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

    <div id="tertiary" class="widget-area" role="supplementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #tertiary .widget-area -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are hard-coded into the sidebar. So you could manually remove them, but they'll just return when you update the theme.

Best solution would be to make a child theme, if possible, and create a new sidebar without the unwanted widgets.

EDIT:

Remove

```
    <aside id="archives" class="widget">
        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'adamos' ); ?></h1>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <aside id="meta" class="widget">
        <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'adamos' ); ?></h1>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_register(); ?>
            <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
            <?php wp_meta(); ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

That should be sufficient.

Comment: I just posted `sidebar.php`, how could I modify that? (I don't mind they come back when I update the theme) Additionally, will it be sufficient to just modify this file?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you... I removed the entire content of the file, that did remove the sidebar. However it seems that there is still space left dedicated to the sidebar, as a result the text is not center aligned. How could I amend this?